# How to move the "All" tab to the right in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins

Is it possible to move the "All" Jenkins tab from the main view all the way right? It's just my browsing preference to see it at the end to not obstruct my always specific habit of using views. In other words, I would like my first view to be what I see at the beginning on the left.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: dragging but it didn't work

Answer (score 6):

One option is to add a new view, remove the "All" view, create a new view, select  "All" and let it start with "z", e.g. "z-all" as the view is sorted alphabetically.

There is [an open issue](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-4242) that indicates that the ordering of tabs in Jenkins is alphabetically sorted and cannot be changed at the moment, e.g. change the order manually.

Comment: This is something that has bothered me about Jenkins for the longest time! The "z-" prepend option was the only solution I could find, but it's FAR from ideal....

Answer (score 3):

I don't have currently any Jenkins instance to test it but what worked 4 years ago is that when you rename tab if you place a space (" ") symbol as name prefix and save it does not show up (since HTML hides trailing and leading spaces) but it takes part in alphabet sorting. So you could move part of tabs to the left or right, or even mix them all as you wish.